# How to setup a basic symfony2 project after cloning it from github

Tags: php, git, symfony, github, configuration

Disclaimer: I'm new to this git thing.

I have made a fresh repository and pushed an standard, empty symfony2 project to it.

Now I have cloned my repo to another folder to test if I can set it up correctly. So far I can't...

The problem is I'm missing some folders such as cache and vendor as these are ignored in the .gitignore.

So when I try to run `$ composer update` I get an error since it tries to clear the cache folder which doesn't exist...

Anyone who can explain in simple terms how to setup a freshly cloned standard symfony2 project?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html

Comment: Yes. If I'm correct that guide mainly focuses on creating the git repo, not on how to configure a downloaded project.

Comment: As the article suggests, after cloning a repository the command composer install (not update) should be run.  This in turn should create the cache directory.  Thereafter, composer update would be run to keep the software up to date.  If you do happen to run into a needed directory then simply check it in with an empty .gitkeep file in it.  But you really should not need to for your basic Symfony config stuff.

Comment: I still get the missing cache folder error even when using `$ composer install`. Maybe it is because of the error, but it also didn't install the bin where the console file is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only problem was the missing bin folder. I made a new symfony project, copy/pasted its bin into my cloned project and ran `$ composer install` as pr. Cerads advice. Then everything went smooth.