# Why is /bin/ added to .gitignore in a symfony2 project? Or is it okay for me to push /bin/ to a remote repo?

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

The other day [I had trouble setting up a cloned symfony2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271297/how-to-setup-a-basic-symfony2-project-after-cloning-it-from-github). I soon discovered all my adversity stemmed from not having the /bin/ folder in my project. After I copy/pasted the /bin from another project, everything worked.

So now I'm considering to remove it from .gitignore to make it problem free to clone it again to another computer in the future.

Is there ANY good reason at all why I wouldn't do this? And why has /bin/ been added to .gitignore in the first place when it creates complications when installing after a clone?

Comment: Git is a source control system, it is not designed to handle large binaries. Not only that, but binaries are dependent on your system. Other people may not be able to run binaries you generate. Adding bin/ to the repo will slow everything down for everyone and clutter the repository. Don't do it.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. Makes good sense. Just wanted to know. You can add your comment as an answer and get a tic if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a source control system, it is not designed to handle large binaries. Not only that, but binaries are dependent on your system. Other people may not be able to run binaries you generate. Adding bin/ to the repo will slow everything down for everyone and clutter the repository. Don't do it.

Comment: While this is normally true, in the case of a symfony project the bin directory only holds a few rather small scripts. You need to check them the scripts (especially bin/console) in.

Comment: And to answer your why question.  app/console was moved to bin/console in 3.0.  The /bin line was removed from .gitignore in 3.0.  2.8 is sort of a transition version. Still a few kinks to work out.

Comment: Ok, super nice! Cerad, If you would add this as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271297/how-to-setup-a-basic-symfony2-project-after-cloning-it-from-github), I'll add that as correct. It's a better answer than the one I came up with.

Comment: Looks like I anticipated your comment.

Comment: Yup you did :P Edited it a bit. Please check it out :)